# How do I tell if a long running update won't lock the database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update, migration, locking

There is a update query I need to run on a table in production. The update would touch millions of rows and I would take a couple of minutes.

The database is Mysql.

I was wondering if the table would be locked during this update? The desired behaviour is that it should not be locked as I still want other operations to be possible while the update is going on.

Is there a way I can check before hand? What could I look for to find out the effect of such query? Is there something like a query plan from where I can see if the table would be locked or not?

Comment: I have to ask why touch a million rows?  Why can't the update be stored in a single row in a separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `UPDATE` **transaction** will always acquire **locks** on the table being updated in some capacity. This is the normal default behavior in all modern relational database management systems. It's just a matter of the type of **lock** and *how long* a particular row stays locked during an `UPDATE`. Depending on the **isolation level** your database is configured for, even though a row may be **locked**, doesn't necessarily mean things like reads of that row will be **blocked**. You can read up more here on [**locks** in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-lock-modes/).

To your follow up question in the comments, depending on the **isolation level**, if an `UPDATE` is **locking** a set of rows that causes **blocking** on other subsequent queries running against those same rows, then those other queries will **wait** until those rows are no longer **locked** by the `UPDATE` query, to execute, in general.

Comment: Quick follow up question...what happens to other operations while a table is being locked due to an update? Are they buffered up to be executed after? or they end up failing?

Comment: @FinlayWeber Read further into **isolation levels** which is linked in the docs I linked, as that will affect the answer. But in general, if the **lock** is blocking other operations, those operations wait until the **lock** is released so that they may execute.